# how to perform sorting and filtering in stored procedure with performance optimization?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to perform sorting and filtering in my stored procedure.

My create table for Holiday table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Holiday](
    [HolidaysId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HolidayDate] [date] NULL,
    [HolidayDiscription] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Holiday] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HolidaysId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My filtering criteria would be as:

1. Starts With
2. Is Equal to
3. Not Equal to.

**Note:Please ignore HolidayId in filter comparision.**

My Table:Holiday

```
HolidaysId int,Name nvarchar(500),HolidayDate date.
```

Sample Input:

```
HolidayId       Name       Date
 1               abc       1/1/2015
 2               pqr       1/2/2015
 3               xyz       1/3/2015
```

Output:

```
Case 1:Starts with(This is just for name column only.likewise i want to do for HolidayDate column too)
Input:ab(filtering parameter)
Query:where Name like '%ab%' order by Name(when sort column name is  passed as parameter in stored procedure for column to sort(for eg:Name))
output:1,abc,1/1/2015

Case 2:Is Equal to(Same as above)
Input:prr(filtering parameter)
output:2,pqr,1/2/2015

Case 3:Not Equal to(Same as above)
Input:bbb(filtering parameter)
output:All Records
```

This is my stored procedure so far:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PagedItems]
    (
     @Page int,
     @RecsPerPage int
    )
AS

-- We don't want to return the # of rows inserted
-- into our temporary table, so turn NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON


--Create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TempItems
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    HolidayDate date
)


-- Insert the rows from tblItems into the temp. table
INSERT INTO #TempItems (ID, Name,HolidayDate)
SELECT HolidaysId,HolidayDiscription,HolidayDate FROM holiday 

-- Find out the first and last record we want
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int
SELECT @FirstRec = (@Page - 1) * @RecsPerPage
SELECT @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1)

-- Now, return the set of paged records, plus, an indiciation of we
-- have more records or not!
SELECT *,
       MoreRecords = 
    (
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM #TempItems TI
     WHERE TI.ID >= @LastRec
    ) 
FROM #TempItems
WHERE ID > @FirstRec AND ID < @LastRec


-- Turn NOCOUNT back OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Now there are 4 things i would send to my stored procedure are:

1. Page no
2. PageSize(number of records to retrive)
3. Sorting Column Name(Name Or HolidayDate)
4. My filter Column name(Name of Holidaydate) and Operator like StartWith or Equal to or not equal to.(ColumnName and Operator)

Can anybody help me to perform sorting and filtering and if any performance optimization related changes is there then please please do suggest me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, I think some sample data and expected results might help. It also seems odd to put your entire table into a tempoarary table then use that. Why not just use the original table? Finally, [you should not prefix your stored procedures with `sp_`](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Please edit your question so that the expected output would be more clear.

Comment: Have you set any indexes on your database?

Comment: @UweAllner:Please see my create table script

Comment: Better, but still not very clear. what exactly do you want to send the procedure? name, date, order by, and case (1,2,3)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled:please see my updated question in the end i have specified what i will pass to my stored procedure

Comment: But your stored procedure does not take any parameter connected to filtering or sorting you've described... How would you like to filter data without it?

BTW. Inserting whole Holiday table into temp table is just wasting memory and electricity - such an operation makes sense only if you filter data before insertion.

Comment: @MaciejNowicki:Sir i am learning to write stored precedure and havent worked much on stored procedure.i have always use linq query and this stored procedure i have taken from website.so i dont know how to use this filter and sorting parameter in stored procedure in query and thing you told me about wastage of memory by using temporary table.i dont have any idea regarding that.so if you could please give me any solution that how do i do this task efficiently i would be very thankfull to you.

Comment: This kind of sql doesn't make a lot of sense.  What would you do if the user choose 'Starts with' and Date? How will you sort your result set if the user choose 'Equals' and the same column to filter and order by?

Comment: @ZoharPeled:at a time only 1 thing will be done like filter or column sorting.Both events are different.http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization.please see this link.I am doing this for kendo grid.both this sorting and filter events are different.i will made a call to my server if there is sorting or if there is filtering.so 2 seperate call to get filtered data or sorted data

Comment: any good solution????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i have done and i am getting expected output but still i want to take improvement suggestion from all of you if there is any.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HolidayFetchList]
@pageno int,
@pagesize int,
@sortorder varchar(10),
@sortcolumn varchar(100),
@filter varchar(max),
@count int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Start int=(@pageno)*@pagesize;
    declare @End int=@Start+@pagesize;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tblHoliday AS TABLE
        (HolidaysId int,HolidayDate date,HolidayDiscription nvarchar(500),HolidayName nvarchar(max),RN int)

    declare @sql varchar(max)= '
    select HolidaysId,HolidayDate,HolidayDiscription,HolidayDiscription as HolidayName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     (ORDER BY '+@sortcolumn + ' '+@sortorder+' ) AS RN from Holiday
     WHERE 1=1 '+@filter
     print @sql
INSERT INTO @tblHoliday
exec (@sql)
select  @count=COUNT(*) from @tblHoliday
print @count
select * from @tblHoliday where RN>@Start and RN<=@End order by RN 
END
```

Please do give me any suggestion if you have any.

Answer (score 4):

I've not tested this, but something like this you can use as starter and do modifications to make it stable:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PagedItems]
    (
    @ID int = NULL,
    @Name varchar(50) = NULL,
    @HolidayDate date = NULL,
    @SortCol varchar(20) = '',
     @Page int=1,
     @RecsPerPage int=10 -- default size, you can change it or apply while executing the SP
    )
AS
BEGIN
-- We don't want to return the # of rows inserted
-- into our temporary table, so turn NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON


--Create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TempItems
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    HolidayDate date
)


-- Insert the rows from tblItems into the temp. table
INSERT INTO #TempItems (ID, Name,HolidayDate)
SELECT HolidaysId, HolidayDiscription, HolidayDate 
FROM holiday 

-- Find out the first and last record we want
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int
SELECT @FirstRec = (@Page - 1) * @RecsPerPage
SELECT @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1)

-- Now, return the set of paged records, plus, an indiciation of we
-- have more records or not!
; WITH CTE_Results
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @SortCol = 'ID_Asc' THEN ID
            END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol = 'ID_Desc' THEN ID
            END DESC, 

        CASE WHEN @SortCol = 'Name_Asc' THEN Name
            END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol = 'Name_Desc' THEN Name
            END DESC, 

        CASE WHEN @SortCol = 'HolidayDate_Asc' THEN HolidayDate
            END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortCol = 'HolidayDate_Desc' THEN HolidayDate
            END DESC
        ) AS ROWNUM,
        ID,
        Name,
        HolidayDate
    FROM #TempItems
    WHERE 
            (@ID IS NULL OR ID = @ID)
        AND (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')
        AND (@HolidayDate IS NULL OR HolidayDate = @HolidayDate)
    )
SELECT 
        ID,
        Name,
        HolidayDate
    FROM CTE_Results
    WHERE
        ROWNUM > @FirstRec 
    AND ROWNUM < @LastRec
    ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC

-- Turn NOCOUNT back OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

You can check the blog posts I've written on:

1. [Creating Stored Procedures with Dynamic Search (filter)](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/12/30/creating-stored-procedures-with-dynamic-search-filter/)
2. [Creating Stored Procedures with Dynamic Search & Paging (Pagination)](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/12/30/creating-stored-procedures-with-dynamic-search-paging-pagination/)
3. [Creating Stored Procedure with Dynamic Search, Paging and Sorting](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/12/30/creating-stored-procedure-with-dynamic-search-paging-and-sorting/)
4. You can also use the FETCH-OFFSET clause for Pagination if you are on SQL 2012 or more, [link](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/07/28/tsql-denali-new-feature-offset-fetch-clause-for-pagingpagination/).

Comment: can you please provide any solution for my existing stored procedure with considering performance if possible

Comment: added the code for SP, check it, but you make need to tweak somewhat as I can't test it.

Comment: but do you think that CTE is required here and one of member suggested in comments that no need to use temporary table and waste memory but still i will upvote your ans because of your kind efforts for me

Comment: Here you have fixed the column name and what if suppose i will add 1 column in future in my holiday table and would like to perform sort and filter on that column then again i have to change this sp (means your sp).

Comment: Yes, no need to use # temp Table, you can directly fetch from holiday table.

Comment: please take a look at my answer and suggest me any improvement which you think is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT recommended to use #temp tables because you can affect the RAM on your server. But, bad news :(, you should NOT use the exec command either... now you are susceptible to SQL Injection in your application. So, I think there are at least two options: 1) Using views (include flag values), table valued-functions and other components; 2) Filtering inside the WHERE statement as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM Holiday
WHERE
CASE WHEN @paramStartDate Is Not Null THEN HolidayDate ELSE '' END
>= CASE WHEN @paramStartDate Is Not Null THEN @paramStartDate ELSE '' END
AND
CASE WHEN @paramEndDate Is Not Null THEN HolidayDate ELSE '' END
<= CASE WHEN @paramEndDate Is Not Null THEN @paramEndDate ELSE '' END
AND
CASE WHEN @paramName Is Not Null THEN [Name] ELSE '' END
LIKE CASE WHEN @paramName Is Not Null THEN '%' + @paramName + '%' ELSE ''  END
```

You should keep in mind that this method can increment the time of process. If so, you have the possibility of creating several stored procedures, one for HolidayDate search, another one for Name search and another one that combines filters. Your application must be able to decide which one to use depending on the input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination (ad-hoc reports) I would use OFFSET and FETCH. Use some advantage of T-SQL, then you won't need temporary tables and any of that mess.